# Using helper methods in Ruby modules

Tags: ruby, oop, methods, module, scope

I'm having some trouble understanding how to incorporate my own helper methods into a Ruby module.

My code:

```rb
module MyModule
  def self.foo
    bar
  end

  def bar
    # helper for MyModule.foo
  end
end

MyModule.foo
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `bar' for MyModule:Module
```

I'm not sure why `MyModule` cannot recognize the `bar` method. What aspect of scope in Ruby am I being oblivious to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modules can be integrated into classes as mixins. So, you need to include it in a class so it can be used with *instance* of that class.

As of now, you can make `bar` as your module method so it can be accessed as is.

```
module MyModule
  def self.foo
    bar
  end
  def self.bar
     puts "Now it works"
  end
end
MyModule.foo #=> Now it works
```

[Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html)

> A Module is a collection of methods and constants. The methods in a
>   module may be instance methods or module methods. Instance methods
>   appear as methods in a class when the module is included, module
>   methods do not.

Comment: Thanks Amit. Would `foo` be considered a class method, even though it does not belong to a class?

Comment: @garythegoat `foo` is a module method.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call an instance method from a class method. You would have to write

```
module MyModule
  def MyModule.foo
    MyModule.bar
  end

  # Or you can have it this way
  def MyModule::bar
    # helper for MyModule.foo
  end
end

MyModule.foo
```

to get what you want.

Comment: This is the best way if you have method's names collision in different modules.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the scope of a method (module as well as instance) and basically it's lifecycle..

**Module method way: -**
Following is how you define the module with module methods.

```
 module MyModule
    def self.foo
        puts "called self.foo"
        bar
    end

    def self.bar
        puts "self.bar got called"
        # helper for MyModule.foo
    end
end
```

Now, This way, you do not have to instantiate any object to call those methods.. Here is how you would call the methods (one inside the other)

```
MyModule.foo
```

Using a class to instantiate the Module and calling methods will not work as they are not instance methods.

Output -

```
called foo
bar got called
```

**Instance method way: -** Following is how you'll define the module with instance methods so that they will work between classes and objects..

```
module MyModule
  def foo
      puts "called foo"
      bar
  end

  def bar
    puts "bar got called"
    # helper for MyModule.foo
  end
end

class TestModule
  include MyModule
end
```

Choosing to use the module methods this way you have to call the methods inside module as per below -

```
#instantiating module MyModule via class
myinstance = TestModule.new
myinstance.foo
```

Output -

```
called foo
bar got called
```